# cordova mp4 file wont play from cdvfile

Tags: cordova, mp4

The 3 files above is downloaded and saved from my app, but **video** won't play or open.

```
<a href="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/files/product/video/10/Ar__A.mp4">video</a>
<a href="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/files/product/image/10/imgres-2.jpg">image</a>
<a href="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/files/product/file/10/imgres-2.pdf">pdf</a>
```

Obs:

- Files Exists (checked)
- If i put the video in the root of www folder and access like a "normal" website the video play and open correctly.

Why only videos have this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sound and video has to be played via Media API. Especially if you are on Android, with iOS some videos will play even without the Media API.

Media API controls the playback and capture of audio and video. It works with the cdvfile protocol. See this link for implementation detail:
[org.apache.cordova.media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/doc/index.md)